# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource Application Context

Tags: java, spring, maven

I wrote the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/org/postprocessor/conf/dataSupport.xml");
    DaoImpl daoImpl=null;
    FileZipper fileZipper=null;
}
```

But when I execute this, I get the following exception:

```
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.postprocessor.dao.DaoMain.main(DaoMain.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 13 more
```

Why did I get this exception even though the file is there?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist` is quite clear imo.

Comment: but the file is there, I can see the package and the file...is there anything am missing out

Comment: I'm sure of what is wrong : it doesn't find your file. 

Are you sure that you xml file is in your classpath ? (look at your output folder, probably in WEB-INF/classes if it's a webapp.

Comment: it's not a webapp, but this file is under this package src org/postprocessor/dataSupport.xml

Comment: but this package is in white color shown in eclipse whereas all other packages, are in brown..does this mean this does not exist...sorry am new to maven projects

Comment: phew got it...just changed 'dataSupport.xml' in the path...thanks a lot for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using maven project it should be in src/main/resources folder.
for example:
[image]